# how in matlab check for existence of a structure with fields in the workspace

Tags: string, matlab, structure

I have a string and want to check if in the workspace exist any variable with the same name. In the workspace I have also many structures M.N.O M.N.N M.N.M etc. I can only check if there exist a variable with the name M. How to go deeper into this structure?
I tried:

```
exist('M.N')
YesNo = any(strcmp(who,'M.N.O'))
evalin('base','exist(''M.N.O'',''var'')')
```

all give me the same problem so I am stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option: write a recursive function to expand structures down to their leaf fields, appending the fields to a list.

(untested, conceptual code - probably won't work quite right as is)

```
function varlist = getStructFields(var,varlist)
if isstruct(var)
    fn = fieldnames(var);
    varlist = vertcat(varlist,fn); %# append fields to the list
    for field = fn' %# ' create row vector; iterate through fields
         varlist = getStructFields(var.(char(field)), varlist); %# recursion here 
    end
end
end
```

Then you can use the `any(strcmp(who,'M.N.O'))` check you already came up with.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [isfield](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/isfield.html) to check if a variable has a specific field. See the link for examples!

For your example, you'd need:

```
isfield(M,'N')
```

and if true, you can go deeper:

```
isfield(M.N,'O')
```

Notice that

```
isfield(M,'N.O')
```

won't work ;)

Comment: And [isstruct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/isstruct.html) to check if the variable is a structure.

Comment: I thought about this solution, but if I have many strings that I want to check, and many structures in the workspace, it is too long to do i this way. I would also have to slice each of the strings between dots, to get names M N O and deeper. That is why I keep searching some other ..